# Passing username and password to Web API

Tags: c#, angular

I have an angular 2 method:

```
login(usernameparam: string, passwordparam: string): Observable<boolean> {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept-Charset': 'utf-16', 'Access-Control': 'Allow - Origin'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:64116/token',
        { username : usernameparam, password: passwordparam },
        options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            debugger;
            let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
            if (token) {
                this.token = token;

                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: usernameparam, token: token }));
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

And a ASP.Net Core method, which receives HttpContext

```
private async Task GenerateToken(HttpContext context)
{
    var username = context.Request.Form["username"];
    var password = context.Request.Form["password"];

    // The rest of the method
}
```

However when I receive that HttpContext, both username and password are empty. When looking at the request from the browser, it clearly states, that Form-Data contains those two. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the form-data from F11 tools?